# Why does Ownable.sol from OpenZeppelin rely so much on the use of functions?

Tags: solidity, gas, security, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I wondered why OpenZeppelin relies so much on the use of functions when, at first glance, they seem unnecessary for such elementary operations. For example, take the [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) contract. Why isn't the modifier strictly

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(_owner == msg.sender, "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    _;
}
```

instead of

```
address private _owner;

modifier onlyOwner() {
    _checkOwner();
    _;
}

function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
    return _owner;
}


function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
    require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
}


// This _msgSender() function is taken from Context.sol
function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
    return msg.sender;
}
```

The way OpenZeppelin has their code written seems to spend more gas, so is security the reason? I get the use of `owner()` and `_checkOwner()` because `owner` is a private variable, but why create functions for such atomic pieces of code like the `_msgSender()`?

P.S.: The code I've transcribed are snippets of [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) and [Context.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol).

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer if you asked this question on the [OpenZeppelin forum](https://forum.openzeppelin.org/)

Comment: As far as I know, the reason why OpenZeppelin complicated their implementations so much is that they wanted to promote the use of [GSN](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/gsn). To my knowledge, this hasn't been a successful project.